# Wrong integer push on the stack

Tags: assembly, gdb, push

Am trying to understand why is the instruction:

```
 pushl  0x4013ea
```

not pushing the value expected but rather I have this on the stack:

```
(gdb) x/wx $esp
0x22ff18:       0xc3899090
```

I am on windows using gdb if that could help

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would bet that 0x4013ea is being treated as a memory address, therefore, the value at that address is being pushed onto stack rather than the literal value itself.

try `pushl $4013ea` (might need to include 0x, depends on your assembler syntax)